# Stuck at login. I can't log in to user profiles after updating to 22.04

Tags: boot, uefi, login, 22.04

I'm on a UEFI HP desktop running only Ubuntu Studio. I've just attempted to update to 22.04 from 21.10, which is no longer supported.

The OS seems to boot OK, but after my entering password at the user login screen, it doesn't load; it just stays on the loading screen. The same happens for the other users of the PC.

Also, I am unable to shut down correctly. I've been using PrtScr REISUB which restarts the boot process. I do get an error message during this shutdown cycle: 'unable to connect to TPM chip'. I'm not sure if this is related. Looking at UEFI/BIOS settings, I can't enable TPM because it says that the password jumper has been removed. As I understand it, that's a connector on the motherboard. I've not touched it.

I haven't been able to load the GTUB menu because `ESC` takes me straight to UEFI/BIOS. `F10` takes it to the system diagnostics screen. The hard drive is fine.

I'd be grateful for help.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to AU. The TPM chip (Trusted Platform Module) is a chip on the motherboard. If enabled the computer will only boot MS Windows. If disabled it should boot any OS which is installed on the harddisk(s) of the computer (has to be reachable for the bootloader of course. You can try to put Ikki Boot.iso (2.6-3 Gb) or Super Grub2 Disk Hybrid .iso (20-25 mb) on a usb stick. Size depends on release. Last mentioned is also integrated in the Ikk Boot iso. This program will find any bootable OS on your computer, and if the OS is installed correctly, it can boot all of them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.